# Solving second-order variable coefficient linear ODE: $y'' + (ax+b)y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $y'' + (ax+b)y = 0$, where $a$ is not equal to zero, the same as $b$.

I know once I've got the first root of this equation, then the general solution can be obtained.

But I don't know how to guess or to calculate the first root of this equation.

Comment: Your idea is probably wrong, there is no easy solution, with a linear transformation this equation is equivalent to the Airy equation.

Comment: When you write "$a$ is not equal to zero, the same as $b$", do you mean that both $a$ and $b$ are not equal to zero? I'm guessing you don't mean that $a$ and $b$ are the same as each other.

Comment: This forms well known Airy differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $$t = -\frac{a x + b}{a^{2 / 3}}$$ transforms the equation to $$y_{tt} - t y = 0,$$
which, as some of the comments mention, is the well-studied [Airy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).
Its solutions are $$y(t) = C \operatorname{Ai}(t) + D \operatorname{Bi}(t),$$
where $\operatorname{Ai}, \operatorname{Bi}$ are respectively the (nonelementary) [Airy functions of the first and second kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Definitions).